# Webpack + react: multiple bundles, same dependencies?

Tags: javascript, webpack, reactjs, laravel-mix

I use Laravel Mix and webpack to compile and combine JSX assets. I have one file with all dependencies (such as React, ReactDOM et al) as well as script components which should be loaded on all pages (*global.js*). Then I use smaller script components for specific pages (*specific.js*).

A typical HTML document would look like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="render-here"></div>
    <script src="/js/global.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/specific.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My mix configuration file looks like this:

```
mix.react([
    'resources/assets/js/search/index.jsx'
], 'public/js/global.js');

// Note: specific isn't actually called "specific", but rather named after its function
// like profile.js for editing user profiles.
mix.react([
    'resources/assets/js/specific/index.jsx'
], 'public/js/specific.js');
```

This isn't optimal, as *specific.js* include the same dependencies as *global.js*. How do I prevent specific components (*specific.js*) from including all the same dependencies already loaded by *global.js*? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using `mix.extract`:

```
mix.extract([
    'react', 'react-dom',
    'react-redux', 'redux',
    'axios',
    'classnames'
]);

mix.react([
    'resources/assets/js/search/index.jsx'
], 'public/js/global.js');

mix.js([
    'resources/assets/js/specific/index.jsx'
], 'public/js/specific.js');
```

It renders two additional scripts: *manifest.js* and *vendor.js* with the aforementioned vendor scripts. You include these scripts above the others:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/manifest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/vendor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/global.js" async></script>
```

More information over here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix